# Why don't commands work together in VIM but only separately?

Tags: vim, command

Consider the following text:

```
com.abc.JavaClassA.doSomething(JavaClassA.java:35)
com.abc.JavaClassA.doSomething(JavaClassA.java:35)
com.abc.JavaClassA$2.doSomething(JavaClassA.java:35)
com.abc.JavaClassA$1.doSomething(JavaClassA.java:35)
```

I run the command:

```
:%s/\v\.[^\.]{-}\(.*\)//ge | g/\v\$[0-9]+$/de | %sort u | %!uniq
```

I expect:

```
com.abc.JavaClassA
```

But the output is:

```
com.abc.JavaClassA
com.abc.JavaClassA$1
```

Why? I thought that `com.abc.JavaClassA$1` should be deleted by `g/\v\$[0-9]+$/de`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [vim's documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#:%5Cbar), `:global` (aka `:g`) is not able to be used in a `|`-delimited command chain as `|` is one of its potential arguments.  You can get around this with `:execute`:

```
:execute 'command1' | 'command2' [...]
```

Comment: Thanks. I've heard about :execute but havent' thought that it can help in this case.